# Find the longest sequence of digits in a string

Tags: c#, string

I am trying to clear up the results for poor quality OCR reads, attempting to remove everything I can safely assume is a mistake.

The desired result is a 6 digit numerical string, so I can rule out any character that isn't a digit from the results. I also know these numbers appear sequentially, so any numbers out of sequence are also very likely to be incorrect.

(Yes, fixing the quality would be best but no... they won't/can't change their documents)

I immediately `Trim()` to remove white space, also as these are going to end up as file names I also remove all illegal characters.

I've found out which Characters are digits and added them to a dictionary against the array position in which they where found.
This leaves me with a clear visual indication of the number sequencies but I am struggling on the logic of how to get my program to recognise this.

Tested with the string "**Oct', 2$3622**" (an actual bad read)
The ideal output for this would be "**3662**"
[image: Obvious to Humans]

```
    public String FindLongest(string OcrText)
    {
        try
        {
            Char[] text = OcrText.ToCharArray();
            List<char> numbers = new List<char>();

            Dictionary<int, char> consec = new Dictionary<int, char>();

            for (int a = 0; a < text.Length; a++)
            {
                if (Char.IsDigit(text[a]))
                {
                    consec.Add(a, text[a]);

                    // Won't allow duplicates?
                    //consec.Add(text[a].ToString(), true);
                }
            }

            foreach (var item in consec.Keys)
            {
                #region Idea that didn't work
                // Combine values with consecutive keys into new list
                // With most consecutive?
                for (int i = 0; i < consec.Count; i++)
                {
                    // if index key doesn't match loop, value was not consecutive
                    // Ah... falsely assuming it will start at 1. Won't work.
                    if (item == i)
                        numbers.Add(consec[item]);
                    else
                        numbers.Add(Convert.ToChar("#")); //string split value
                }
                #endregion
            }

            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string message;

            if (ex.InnerException != null)
                message =
                    "Exception: " + ex.Message +
                    "\r\n" +
                    "Inner: " + ex.InnerException.Message;
            else
                message = "Exception: " + ex.Message;
            MessageBox.Show(message);

            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, but what is your question? What are you having difficulties with?

Comment: Can you give some examples of `input : expected` output ? You want to read fuzzily? ie: `2$3622 : 23622` or `2$3622: 3622`?

Comment: OK. Sorry, knowing the issue I didn't realise it was not a clear question.
*edits in progress*

Comment: Side note (though I don't understand the actual question): Instead of wrapping the full thing in a `try`/`catch`, you can used `if (!consec.ContainsKey(a))` before inserting into the Dictionary - this will prevent the only exception that I can see your code throwing (could've missed one though)

Comment: I cannot - for the life of me - figure out exactly what you're trying to do, and/or what the output of the function _should_ be. Can you tells us what you're inputs are, what your outputs **should** be, and exactly what you're having trouble with. Thanks.

Comment: Let me see if I understand your needs, you want to reject every string that is not six characters long, a number, and all numbers occur in uninterrupted sequence 123456 is ok, 123567 is not, correct?

Comment: Negative @Chris, although that helps me see where I was confusing people.

If I put in "ad 232h3524 345" I would want "3524" out.

Comment: So, the longest sequence of digits in the string? What happens if there is more than one sequence of the same length?

Comment: @Oded yes, and you are correct that would be an issue. By I am unlikely to get enough digits for that to happen, as there are no other numbers nearby on the document.

The best solution would be to modify the documents font but that's not an option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick and dirty way to get the longest sequence of digits would be by using a Regex like this:

```
var t = "sfas234sdfsdf55323sdfasdf23";

var longest = Regex.Matches(t, @"\d+").Cast<Match>().OrderByDescending(m => m.Length).First();

Console.WriteLine(longest);
```

This will actually get all the sequences and obviously you can use LINQ to select the longest of these.

This doesn't handle multiple sequences of the same length.

Comment: Hi Brian, thank you for your answer. This is one of those cases where I am having to fix a problem in code that should be fixed elsewhere, so I can't envision a super clean solution.

I am not familiar with Regex, outside of verifying e-mail addresses, so I didn't consider it for this sort of purpose. Cheers!

Comment: You're welcome. Keep in mind that this code is a bit rough around the edges, so you may have to polish it a bit to get the desired behavior.

Answer (score 1):

so you just need find the longest # sequence? why not use regex?

```
  Regex reg = new Regex("\d+");
  Matches mc = reg.Matches(input);
  foreach (Match mt in mc)
  {
     // mt.Groups[0].Value.Length is the len of the sequence
     // just find the longest
  }
```

Just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

Since you strictly want numeric matches, I would suggest using a regex that matches `(\d+)`.

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"(\d+)");
string longest = string.Empty;
foreach (Match match in matches) {
    if (match.Success) {
        if (match.Value.Length > longest.Length) longest = match.Value;
    }
}
```

This will give you the number of the longest length. If you wanted to actually compare values (which would also work with the "longest length", but could solve an issue with same-length matches):

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"(\d+)");
int biggest = 0;
foreach (Match match in matches) {
    if (match.Success) {
        int current = 0;
        int.TryParse(match.Value, out current);
        if (current > biggest) biggest = current;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var split = Regex.Split(OcrText, @"\D+").ToList();

var longest = (from s in split
               orderby s.Length descending
               select s).FirstOrDefault();
```

I would recommend using a Regex.Split using \D (@"\D+" in code) which finds all characters that are not digits.  I would then perform a Linq query to find the longest string by .Length.

As you can see, it's both simple and very readable.

Comment: You ought to add a sentence or two explaining with this is the best choice rather than just posting code.

Comment: This finds the longest sequence of non-digits. Also, the code refers to both `split` and `split2`, so it doesn't compile as it stands.